# Create and Publish nuget packages from TFS build process?

Tags: tfs, nuget, publish

I want to create nuget packages (and deploy them to my private nuget repository) after my assemblies are compiled.

I tried setting everything up by using NuGetter, but that project is kind of inactive and only allows you to build one package/project while I need one package/assembly.

Now I'm kind of stuck. I'm currently looking at their source, hoping to make it more useable for me.

What I'm asking here, in parallel, is: Does anyone have a finished solution for publishing/creating nuget packages from TFS 2012 and/or TFS2010 for multi-package solutions?

Comment: Have you checked ALM Rangers' "TFS Version Control guidance - Dependency Management with NuGet" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I tried setting everything up by using NuGetter, but that project is kind of inactive and only allows you to build one package/project while I need one package/assembly.
```

NuGetter does support multiple packages, i only use the multiple package method now as you can use it for single or multiple packages.

by using a packages xml file you can specify the multiple packages

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NuGetterPackages>
  <NuGetterPackage name="Package1">
    <NuSpecFilePath>Package1.nuspec</NuSpecFilePath>
    <BasePath>NuGetPrePackage_Package1</BasePath>
    <InvokePowerShell>True</InvokePowerShell>
    <PowerShellScriptPath>PrePackage_Package1.ps1</PowerShellScriptPath>
    <InvokePush>True</InvokePush>
    <OutputDirectory>NuGetPackage</OutputDirectory>
    <PushDestination>\\MYFeedLoc\NugetFeed</PushDestination>
    <Version>1.0.J.B</Version>
  </NuGetterPackage>
<NuGetterPackage name="Package2">
    <NuSpecFilePath>Package2.nuspec</NuSpecFilePath>
    <BasePath>NuGetPrePackage_Package2</BasePath>
    <InvokePowerShell>True</InvokePowerShell>
    <PowerShellScriptPath>PrePackage_Package2.ps1</PowerShellScriptPath>
    <InvokePush>True</InvokePush>
    <OutputDirectory>NuGetPackage</OutputDirectory>
    <PushDestination>\\MYFeedLoc\NugetFeed</PushDestination>
    <Version>1.0.J.B</Version>
  </NuGetterPackage>
</NuGetterPackages>
```

under source control i have the packages.xml file, and then per Nuget Package a powershell file and a nuspec file.

Nuspec File looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Package1</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>Package1</title>
    <authors>Package1 Author</authors>
    <owners>Package1 Owner</owners>
    <iconUrl>http://Iconserver/nextlogo.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description of Contents</description>
    <releaseNotes>First release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2014</copyright>
    <tags>Space Seperated Tags</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="AnyLatestDependencyIMayHAve" version=""/> 
      <dependency id="AFixedDependencyIMayHAve" version="[1.0.0]"/>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

And then a Powershell file that just creates the folder structure within the BasePathDeclaration in the Packages.xml, this is the same file as shown on the NuGetter site

I have added a full explanation at my [blog](http://blog.justtfs.co.uk/2014/09/creating-nuget-packages-using-nugetter.html)

Comment: so that's what that should look like. Thanks :). But why do you specify a nuspec file for every project? How does that work? As far as I read, those files are created before building a package?!

Comment: Have expanded the answer. everything is created before hand. the build runs. a 'BasePath' folder is created and the powershell script will create the desired structure in there, and will then copy the package dll's into that structure. NuGet is then run against the structure to create the package